# How to continue sequence number during insert based on select - Postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, select, insert, where-clause

I am using PostgreSQL db. I have two tables as shown below

[image]

I would like to add the missing person_ids in Table_2 by referring records from Table_1.

If you see the above tables, you can notice that person_id = 2,4 from table_1 is missing in table_2.

Though I am able to do this with help from forum, **the problem is with the not null constraint.**

Table 2 create table definition is like as shown below

```
CREATE TABLE Table_2(
   SNO INTEGER (20) UNIQUE NOT NULL,
   PERSON_ID INTERGER (20) NOT NULL,
   date_1 DATE NOT NULL,
   date_2 DATE NOT NULL,
   DEPT VARCHAR (10) NOT NULL
);
```

[image]

This is what I tried

```
INSERT into Table_2 (person_id,date_1,date_2,Dept) (select distinct person_id,TO_DATE('1900-01-01', 'YYYY-MM-DD'),TO_DATE('2900-12-30', 'YYYY-MM-DD'),'F' from Table_1 where person_id not in (select distinct person_id from Table_2))
```

This results in error as shown below

```
`ERROR: null value in column "SNO" violates not-null constraint
DETAIL: Failing row contains (null, 2, 1900-01-01, 2900-12-30, F).
SQL state: 23502`
```

I expect my output to be like as shown below. Please note that my real data has more than 50K records and the newly added records should continue the sequence as is.

[image]

Comment: I told you in your last question not to use images for tables. Yet you do it again...

Comment: Please show the `CREATE TABLE` for table 1. What is the difference between `SNO` and `person_id` in table 1?

Comment: Hi @VesaKarjalainen - made some changes to the table. You can see the updated post. now `sno` column isn't there in `table_1`

Comment: Does `table_1` have a `sno` column? Does `sno` in `table_2` have a sequence or is it a serial column?

Comment: That's not a `CREATE TABLE` command, and that's not table 1. That's not table 2 either, does it have a 'gender' and/or a 'dept'? And do not post images, post code someone can copy-paste.

Comment: @JimJones - Only Table_2 has `SNO` column. It is a sequence column

Comment: @VesaKarjalainen - Here is the create statmt `CREATE TABLE Table_2(
   SNO INTEGER (20) UNIQUE NOT NULL,
   PERSON_ID INTERGER (20) NOT NULL,
   date_1 DATE NOT NULL,
   date_2 DATE NOT NULL,
   DEPT VARCHAR (10) NOT NULL
);`

Comment: updated the post too

Comment: Maybe you'd like to fill `SNO` in `table 2` automatically from a sequence? There seldom is any point in having serial number field without automatic serial numbers. (Unless we talk about serial numbers of physical parts or like.)

Comment: Yes. When I insert the missing record into `Table_2`, I would like it to automatically get a `SNO`. Is it possible?

Comment: You define it as `SERIAL` or with `DEFAULT` and a sequence in `CREATE TABLE`. Or add a sequence and a trigger, but that might be slower on large inserts. Or there are more complicated ways, too.

Answer (score 1):

If `sno` in `table_2` is has a sequence or is a serial column, try this

Sample data

```
CREATE TABLE table_1 (person_id int, day_of_birth int, month_of_birth int, gender text);
INSERT INTO table_1 
VALUES (4,17,7,'M'),
       (2,15,3,'F');

CREATE TABLE table_2 (sno serial, person_id int, date_1 date, date_2 date, dept text);

INSERT INTO table_2 (person_id, date_1, date_2, dept)
VALUES (1,'1990-02-27','2020-03-13','A'),
       (3,'1990-02-28','2020-02-14','B');
```

Insert query

```
INSERT into Table_2 (person_id,date_1,date_2,dept) 
SELECT person_id, 
       TO_DATE('1900-01-01', 'YYYY-MM-DD'), 
       TO_DATE('2900-12-30', 'YYYY-MM-DD'),'F' 
FROM Table_1 WHERE person_id NOT IN (SELECT person_id FROM Table_2);
```

Result

```
SELECT * FROM table_2;
 sno | person_id |   date_1   |   date_2   | dept 
-----+-----------+------------+------------+------
   1 |         1 | 1990-02-27 | 2020-03-13 | A
   2 |         3 | 1990-02-28 | 2020-02-14 | B
   3 |         4 | 1900-01-01 | 2900-12-30 | F
   4 |         2 | 1900-01-01 | 2900-12-30 | F
(4 Zeilen)
```

**Edit** (see comments)

Create a [`sequence`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/sql-createsequence.html)

```
CREATE SEQUENCE seq_sno START WITH 3;
```

After that just place it in your insert using `nextval`

```
INSERT INTO Table_2 (sno, person_id,date_1,date_2,dept) 
SELECT nextval('seq_sno'),person_id, 
       TO_DATE('1900-01-01', 'YYYY-MM-DD'), 
       TO_DATE('2900-12-30', 'YYYY-MM-DD'),'F' 
FROM Table_1 WHERE person_id NOT IN (SELECT person_id FROM Table_2);

SELECT * FROM table_2;
 sno | person_id |   date_1   |   date_2   | dept 
-----+-----------+------------+------------+------
   1 |         1 | 1990-02-27 | 2020-03-13 | A
   2 |         3 | 1990-02-28 | 2020-02-14 | B
   3 |         4 | 1900-01-01 | 2900-12-30 | F
   4 |         2 | 1900-01-01 | 2900-12-30 | F
(4 Zeilen)
```

Comment: That'll fail. `SNO` is `NOT NULL` with no `DEFAULT`, you have to give it a value.

Comment: Is it any different from the code that I have given in the post?

Comment: @TheGreat check the create table statement I posted. It automatically sets the value of sno sequentially without passing it in the insert

Comment: Okay, Unfortunately I cannot use `create statement`.

Comment: @TheGreat do you have permissions to create a `sequence`?

Comment: I am working on already built data model with certain definitions. I cannot change them in the source. So, I can only insert records that meets the requirements of the table.

Comment: @TheGreat I realize that. Creating a sequence you don't need to touch the data model at all. I just added this option to my answer

Comment: This would be fine if this was the only way to insert new data to table 2. If there are also other ways to insert new rows, I'd go with a trigger.

Comment: @VesaKarjalainen very good point! If there are other clients already inserting data into this table and you cannot modify them to use this sequence, it will also fail. And although creating a trigger for a sequence seems a little exaggerated, I believe it would be the less harmful option:)

Answer (score 1):

Under most circumstances where a table has an integer primary key, it is assigned using:

- `serial`
- `generated always as identity`
- a sequence number, perhaps set automatically using a trigger
- means something that is defined by the business

Your table seems to be missing that.  I would recommend fixing the table, but if you cannot, you can try:

```
insert into Table_2 (sno, person_id, date_1, date_2, Dept)
    select t2.max_sno + row_number() over (order by t1.person_id),
           t1.person_id, date '1900-01-01', date '2900-12-30', 'F' 
    from Table_1 t1 cross join
         (select max(t2.sno) as max_sno from table_2 t2) t2
    where not exists (select 1
                      from table_2 t2
                      where t2.person_id = t1.person_id
                     );
```

I don't really recommend this approach, except as a work-around.  The correct approach is to fix the table.

Notes:

- Use simple date constants.  This uses the `date` keyword but you can also use `'2020-01-01'::date`
- `NOT EXISTS` is preferable to `NOT IN` because it handles `NULL` values.
- The entire `WHERE` clause is not the best approach to protect against duplicates.  A better approach would use `on conflict` (or even both together).

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response. upvoted. but this throws error `ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table "t2"`   but `from clause is present`